# code prepending url to link

Tags: url, anchor

My PHP is prepending the pages URL into my link for some reason.

Links that should have a value of `#` come out as `mysite.com/url_the_page/page.php#` and idea what would cause this?

```
echo'<a href="#" id="bb">click me</a></span>';
echo '<a href="#" id="song_'. $row[id].'">';
echo $artist_title;
echo '</a></span>';`
```

Full code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

        if ($row[sourcefile] !== NULL )
        {


            echo '';


            if ( $row[artist] !== NULL && $row[title] !== NULL)
            {
                $artist_title = $row[artist] . ' - ' . $row[title];
            }
            else
            {
                $artist_title = $row[originalfilename];
            }



            echo "<a href=http://".$row[link].' target="_blank">LINK</a> - ';

            if ( $row[listened] == 0)
            {
                $link_class = "unlistened";
            }
            else
            {
                $link_class = "listened";
            }

            $size = $row[size];
            $size = round(($size / 1000000),2);

            if ( $size > 30 )
            {
                echo '<font color="red">MIX </font>';
            }

            echo '<span id="'.$row[id].'" class="'.$link_class.'">';                

            echo '<a href="#" id="song_'. $row[id].'">';
            echo $artist_title;
            echo '</a></span>';

            echo ' - ';

            //turn size into MB
            $size = $row[size];
            $size = round(($size / 1000000),2);

            //if the song is smaller than a certain size display the size as red.   
            if ( $row[size] < 1500000)
            {
                echo '<font color="red">';
                echo $size;
                echo '</font>';
            }
            else
            {
                //echo $row[size];
                echo $size;
            }

            echo 'MB<br>';

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP, but is the default behaviour of your browser.

`#` is not a valid URL, but a so-called [Fragment Identifier.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) It has a special meaning in URLs, directing the browser to look for an anchor of that name in the target document. A URL pointing to `#` only will point to the current document's beginning.

I'm not sure what you want to do, but URLs must not contain this character in their address part.

Comment: How come this is used to handle links for JavaScrip/JQuery and so on then? And what should I use instead?

Comment: I have a series of links.. When they are clicked I handle them with Jquery rather than them linking to a page.

Comment: javascript uses it because it's the only part of the URL that can be changed without the browser loading a new page

Comment: Andrew67 is absolutely correct. `#`'s are interpreted by browsers only. And you actually want to avoid showing this interaction to users, if possible.

Comment: @Andrew67 yes i'm using it with JQuery. And I do an almost identical setup on another page and it works fine.

Comment: @ian: I assume you have bound an onclick event to the link and when you click the link it appends the # ? If this is the case try to return false in your onClick event like this: $('a.clickable').click(function() { /* your code here */ return false; });

Comment: @sled im using `onClick` and `event.preventDefault(event);` but I was more curious as to why in another page it displays as `#` and this one the full url plus the `#`

Comment: @ian: Can you post the generated HTML links?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is a normal behaviour, if you have a link with name categories, eg:

```
<a name="categories"></a>
```

Then you would link to that section of the page using the following url

```
mysite.com/index.html#categories
```